# Add a set number of days to an expression in PowerShell

Tags: date, powershell, expression, addition

I have the following script and I want to be able to add 270 days to the commented out Password Expiration expression, is this possible and how?  I would also like to be able to create another column that can show the difference between today's date and the expiration date.

```
import-module activedirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | 
sort-object -property SamAccountName |  
Format-Table -property `
                        @{Name="Logon Name";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}},
                        @{Name="First Name";Expression={$_.givenName}},
                        @{Name="Initials";Expression={$_.Initials}},
                        @{Name="Last Name";Expression={$_.SN}},
                        @{Name="Email Address";Expression={$_.EmailAddress}},
                        @{Name="Password Last Set";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet}},
                        ##@{Name="Password Expiration";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet}},
                        @{Name="Last Logon";Expression={$_.LastLogonDate}}`
                        -AutoSize | 
                        Out-File C:\ADUsers.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you even tried to solve this yourself? Does this work?

```
@{Name="Password Expiration";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(270)}},
@{Name="DifferenceDays";Expression={($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(270) - [DateTime]::Now).Days}},
...
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried to solve this.  I am very new to PS and I am getting the basics down.  I appreciate your help on this.  The password expiration worked.  The second line just outputs 270, not the difference between today's date and the password expiration.

Comment: This works, just need to truncate it to just days. @{Name="DifferenceDays";Expression={($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(270) - [DateTime]::Now)}},

Comment: Yeah, sorry. A small typo that made a big impact. :)

Answer (score 0):

Might try using Add-Member to create a property before piping in your table.

i.e.

```
... | Sort-Object -Property SamAccountName | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Expiration -value ((get-date($_.passwordLastSet)).addDays(270)) | Format-Table ...
```